# The caret is moved in an expected place when I add/remove a space in text I before entered in a textarea field

Tags: macos, safari

I notice this behavior all times I move a sentence on a separate line: I delete a space character between two words with the backspace key, and the text cursor is moved to the next space; when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the first word is left on the old line.

Is this a bug, a feature of Safari, or neither of them? (Therefore, it is a bug in third-party software)?

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

[image: third screenshot]

I noticed that something similar is still happening with OS X 10.8.3 and Safari 6.0.4: When I edit something I have written before, adding a space moves the caret to the end of the sentence I am editing. It doesn't happen all times, and I am not able to understand when it happens.
I don't have any utility that intercepts the pressed keys or the mouse clicks; the settings for symbol and text substitution and automatically correcting the spelling are disabled.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to reproduce this on a MacBook Air running Mac OS X 10.6.6 and Safari 5.0.3. When I press backspace (it's called <kbd>delete</kbd> on my keyboard), it doesn't cause the carat to jump to the next word.

Perhaps it's some 3rd party software interfering with your keyboard?